# How to change the fontenc parameters in org-mode latex export

Tags: org-mode, org-export

In the org-mode LaTeX-export the `fontenc` package is loaded by default with the `T1` option. Since my document contains a few characters like `ȩ` or `ĭ` which are not contained in `T1` I would like to load additional font encodings.

Which variables do I have to change in order to achieve this? Ideally I would like to do this in a local variable.

In addition, is there a way to guarantee that `fontenc` is loaded before `inputenc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default list of packages is stored in `org-latex-default-packages-alist`:

> Alist of default packages to be inserted in the header.
>
> Change this only if one of the packages here causes an
>   incompatibility with another package you are using.

Each element of this list is a triple `("options" "package" SNIPPET-FLAG)`.  As you've seen, the entry for `fontenc` is `("T1" "fontenc" t)` and it is loaded after `inputenc`.

You can reorder and change the options by customizing this variable.  Parts of `org-mode` make assumptions about what packages get loaded, so it's probably a bad ideal to *remove* anything from this list.

Comment: This requires that we re-define the variable, which is not ideal (for example, if some packages we install later "touch" the variable, then our changes will override theirs). Is there a way to affect the options of a particular package in that list without affecting other packages in the list?

Comment: You can change the variable without just overwriting it.  You could, for example use `remove-if` to delete only a single entry.